# responsive css animations possible ?

Tags: html, css, animation, responsive-design

I making a website for a friend of mine. But the thing is there are some css animations in it.

I was wondering if this could be made responsive ?

```
.waaier3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    left: 39%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;

    -webkit-animation:spindrie 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spindrie 4s linear infinite;
    animation:spindrie 4s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spindrie { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spindrie { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spindrie { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

By made responsive I mean: scale along with the screensize, and stay on the same position according to the screen size?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the viewport settings! For example, instead of using %, you could use vw (viewport width) for the width and vh (viewport height) for the height!

Answer (score 0):

```
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
```

Im sure if you change you  that its in to:

```
    .divblahblahblah{

     height:80px;
     width:80px;


}
```

Set your .waaier3  inside that and change:

```
.waaier3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    left: 39%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
```

to

```
.waaier3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    left: 39%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
```

Hopefully that works :P